# Sscanf to device for reading lines with offset

Tags: c, linux, kernel, device, sysfs

I've created a user space program that reads from a text file into a buffer, and writes it to device using `fprintf` and the store function from said device.

The user space program is supposed to write the entire buffer and send it into the store function's buf parameter.

```c
//store function for chardev

ssize_t modify(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)    //sysfs store/write implementation - add new rule
```

Then the device is supposed the read the strings from the buffer 9 by 9 (hard coded size of line in the buffer).

```c
for(j=0;j<=num_of_rules;j++){

    if((read=sscanf(buf,"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%n",
                    rule_name, direction_string, src_ip,
                    dst_ip, src_port_string, dst_port_string,
                    protocol_string, ack_string, action_string, &offset))==9)
    {
        printk("offset = %u",offset);
```

EDIT: Adding pictures of the run attempt

Picture 1: Running the user space program and printing the contents of buf:
[image]

Picture 2: Running dmesg and showing that the data has been written to the kernel module. Also, the offset is 59, the length of the first line:

[image]

The reading of the first line goes fine, and the offset is correct, but when I try to advance buf with the offset using `buf+=offest`, the next run kills the process and prints "Killed".

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, could you provide an example of file being read? (like 2-3 lines) and the associated `offset = ` provided by the kernel.

Comment: Sure,my problem is that only one line is being read. Anything more than one line casues the kernel to get stuck, and the process prints out "Killed". But I will update the post to contain the writing of a single line and the corresponding offset.

Comment: Also, the error message is since I'm not moving the buffer, it attempts to read line number 1 twice.
When I do try to move the buffer, the process gets killed.

Comment: @Mathieu did the pictures help?

Comment: Please, do NOT use **images** (pictures) for represent a **textual** information. Instead, copy paste the corresponded text into the question post itself. Two lines of code is definitely not sufficient for find a problem in it. We also need a code of your user space program (Hint: Instead of writing user space program, you could output content of your device file using `cat` utility). You could find [mcve] to be useful as a way for represent your problem.